# How to add a SSL certificate after running Web2py 'one step production deployment'

Tags: python, linux, ssl, web2py

I have set up a web2py environment on a linux server using the 'one step production deployment' descriped in the web2py document.
Now I can go to my website by typing my domain name into a web browser, except now it is untrusted by the browser.

Then I got a ssl certificate that I want to add to my server.
So my question is how to add ssl certificate after using the one step deployment?

I searched online, but most tutorial is to setup every thing from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look into the `one-step-production-deployment` script, you can see that it generated a self-signed cert:

```
echo "creating a self signed certificate"
echo "=================================="
openssl genrsa 1024 > /etc/apache2/ssl/self_signed.key
chmod 400 /etc/apache2/ssl/self_signed.key
openssl req -new -x509 -nodes -sha1 -days 365 -key /etc/apache2/ssl/self_signed.key > /etc/apache2/ssl/self_signed.cert
openssl x509 -noout -fingerprint -text < /etc/apache2/ssl/self_signed.cert > /etc/apache2/ssl/self_signed.info
```

And let Apache use it:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/self_signed.cert
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/self_signed.key
  # ...
```

So I think what you need to do is changing the path above to your new cert.

Comment: Although this solution requires a re-run of the setup script, I accept the answer because it shows the origin of my problem and let me find out my way of solving it.
What I do is to replace the .cert file and the .key file in /etc/apache2/ssl with my new certification and private key. Then restart the apache server by: sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
Then everything is working perfectly, without re-run everything